# Checking if numbers of an integer are increasing (java)

Tags: java, arrays, integer

What I am trying to do should be pretty easy, but as I'm new to java, I'm struggling with what might be basic programming.

The main issue is how to check if the (x+1) number of an integer is greater than the x number, which I am trying to do as follow :

```
for( int x=0; x < Integer.toString(numblist).length();x++) {            
    if (numblist[x] < numblist[x+1]) {
        compliance= "OK";
    } else{
        compliance="NOK";
}
```

But it returns an error "array required but integer found".
It seems to be a basic type mistake, which might come from the previous step (keeping only the numbers included in a string):

```
 for (int p = 0; p < listWithoutDuplicates.size(); p++) {

      Integer numblist =  Integer.parseInt(listWithoutDuplicates.get(p).getVariantString().replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

I can't find the answer online, and the fact that it shouldn't be complicated drives me crazy, I would be grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: number of an integer is the digit?

Comment: Do the variantStrings contain numbers (can be greater then 9) or digits (allways smaller then 10)?

Comment: yes the digit, always smaller than 10, sorry if I was unclear. I just want to make sure that the digits keep increasing (e.g. 13689 = OK and 15739 = Not OK)

Answer (score 4):

Do the reverse. If they are increasing starting from the first digit, it means that they are decreasing from the last to the first. And it is much easier to program this way:

```
public boolean increasingDigits(int input)
{
    // Deal with negative inputs...
    if (input < 0)
        input = -input;

    int lastSeen = 10; // always greater than any digit
    int current;

    while (input > 0) {
        current = input % 10;
        if (lastSeen < current)
            return false;
        lastSeen = current;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't index an integer (i.e. `numblist`) using the `[]` syntax -- that only works for arrays, hence your error. I think you're making this more complicated than it has to be; why not just start from the back of the integer and check if the digits are *decreasing*, which would avoid all this business with strings:

```
int n = numblist;
boolean increasing = true;

while (n > 0) {
    int d1 = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    int d2 = n % 10;

    if (d2 > d1) {
        increasing = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought there was a problem with the type of numblist. Thank you very much, I'll try this ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think of was this:

```
boolean checkNumber(int n) {
    String check = String.valueOf(n); // Converts n to string.
    int length = check.length(); // Gets length of string.
    for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
        if(check.charAt(i) <= check.charAt(i+1)) { // Uses the charAt method for comparison.
            continue; // if index i <= index i+1, forces the next iteration of the loop.
        }
        else return false; // if the index i > index i+1, it's not an increasing number. Hence, will return false.
    }
    return true; // If all digits are in an increasing fashion, it'll return true.
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this will solve the problem and what it is doing.

Comment: @Svenmarim, thanks for your feedback man. I added some comments. Hope that helps bro.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're checking the individual digits within the integer. If so, it would be best to convert the Integer to a string and then loop though the characters in the string.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer num = 234; // New Integer
        String string = num.toString(); // Converts the Integer to a string
        // Loops through the characters in the string
        for(int x = 0; x < string.length() - 1; x++){
            // Makes sure that both string.charAt(x) and string.charAt(x+1) are integers
            if(string.charAt(x) <= '9' && string.charAt(x) >= '0' && string.charAt(x+1) <= '9' && string.charAt(x+1) >= '0'){
                if(Integer.valueOf(string.charAt(x)) < Integer.valueOf(string.charAt(x+1))){
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("NOK");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your way of doing it is different than the others', so I'll try both and keep the fastest one. Thank you very much for the fast answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way could be this

```
    package javacore;

import java.util.Scanner;

// checkNumber
public class Main_exercise4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // Local Declarations
        int number;
        boolean increasingNumber=false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = input.nextInt();
        increasingNumber = checkNumber(number);
        System.out.println(increasingNumber);
    }
    public static boolean checkNumber(int number) {
        boolean increasing = false;
        while(number>0) {
            int lastDigit = number % 10;
            number /= 10;
            int nextLastDigit = number % 10;
            
            if(nextLastDigit<=lastDigit) {
                increasing=true;
            }
            else {
                increasing=false;
                break;
            }
            
        }
        return increasing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
private boolean isIncreasingOrder(int num) {
        String value = Integer.toString(num);
        return IntStream.range(0, value.length() - 1).noneMatch(i -> Integer.parseInt(value.substring(i, i + 1)) > Integer.parseInt(value.substring(i + 1, i + 2)));
}
```